# Nginx Stream SSL Error 500 on Connection to Synology

Tags: ssl, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, synology

hi @ all i have a problem with pass through the TCP Communication to a Synology NAS with SSL.
I want to connect with the Synology Drive Client to the NAS, and the Drive Client Software communicate over the TCP Port 6690 with the NAS.
When i try to connect i get an 500 Error.
Without SSL it works fine, but than the Synology encrypt the communication with a own untrusted Cert., that should not be the solution.

The Build:

Internet| --> |Router(Port forwarding 6690)| --> |nginx| -->| NAS(192.168.10.2)|

Nginx:

```
stream{


        log_format log_stream '$remote_addr [$time_local] $protocol [$ssl_preread_server_name] [$ssl_preread_alpn_protocols]'
        '$status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time';

         access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log log_stream;

         ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{mydomain}/fullchain.pem;
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{mydomain}/privkey.pem;
         ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

   server {
         listen 6690 ssl;
         proxy_pass 192.168.10.2:6690;
       }
}
```

Log:

```
xx.xx.xxx.xxx [08/Nov/2019:15:09:37 +0100] TCP [-] [-]500 0 0 0.000
xx.xx.xxx.xxx [08/Nov/2019:15:09:37 +0100] TCP [-] [-]500 0 0 0.000
xx.xx.xxx.xxx [08/Nov/2019:15:10:37 +0100] TCP [-] [-]500 0 0 0.000
xx.xx.xxx.xxx [08/Nov/2019:15:10:37 +0100] TCP [-] [-]500 0 0 0.000
xx.xx.xxx.xxx [08/Nov/2019:15:11:37 +0100] TCP [-] [-]500 0 0 0.000
xx.xx.xxx.xxx [08/Nov/2019:15:11:37 +0100] TCP [-] [-]500 0 0 0.000
```

i also try to check the SSL handshake with:

```
openssl s_client -host mydomain.net -port 6690
```

and that works fine.

Does somebody has any idea where is my mistake??? :-(

Answer (score 0):

Similar setup with the goal to provide access to Synology Drive behind "safer" Rev-Proxy.

The problem is not the SSL handshake.

The problem is: no http protocol running no port 6690 for Synology Drive etc. (Reference in German, contains assumptions about non-http protocol on 6690: [https://www.synology-forum.de/showthread.html?74773-Cloud-Station-über-Reverse-Proxy/page3](https://www.synology-forum.de/showthread.html?74773-Cloud-Station-%C3%BCber-Reverse-Proxy/page3))

In addition, I call with the Drive-Client to my NginxRevProxy (which is working in general) and get from the access.log:

`172.18.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2019:10:17:26 +0000] "%R\x18\x14F\x0B\x00\x00" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"`

So your approach (and mine) are not sufficient.

Possible path to a solution, which is beyond my current knowledge: 
"Upgrade" Nginx to a reverse tcp-proxy, if this works with Synology Drive, use "fancyness" of Nginx in conjunction with own auth-script within and for the TCP-Proxy. (i.e. "abuse" + extend the TCP-Loadbalancer shown here: https://www.debinux.de/2014/12/nginx-als-tcp-proxy-beispiel-dovecot/)

Comment: Sounds you define your Synology pass through in the http block ???